# What's the difference between "author" and "user" in Tweepy's user object?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy, a Twitter API wrapper for Python, to automate some activities on Twitter.

Tweepy's status object has an attribute named `author`, which shows the information of the author of a specific tweet, but it also has another attribute named `user`.

There are some differences between these two attributes but both seem to be the information of 'the same user'.

Are there some cases where `author` and `user` show different user's information? If so, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go and read the [source](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L83-L84) on GitHub, you will find:

```
            setattr(status, 'author', user)
            setattr(status, 'user', user)  # DEPRECIATED
```

so I would use the `author` attr.